# finding a stray puts in ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a fairly large rails application and I have started this output in our unicorn.log:

```
#:0xc644248>#:0xc644248>#:0xc4f06e4>#:0xc4f06e4>#:0xca481b4>#:0xca481b4>#:0xc53f604>#:0xc53f604>#:0xcd7a60c>#:0xcd7a60c>#:0xc5df2f8>#:0xc5df2f8>#:0xc69fd00>#:0xc69fd00>#:0xc560ae8>#:0xc560ae8>
```

It seems to me like there probably is a stray Kernel.puts method call somewhere, but I've been searching for hours and can't find it.

Anyone have tips for tracking something like this down?

Comment: Because the output does not contain any newlines, I am starting to think this is a call to print, not puts.

Comment: This could also be a call to pp, which does not seem to go through print or puts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked for `display`? That's another method that prints stuff out.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, this was the issue.

Answer (score 9):

You could monkey patch puts, and raise an exception when it's called. You could even fine tune that with a regexp match on your output string (which looks like a recursive object dump).

```
module Kernel
  def puts (s)
    raise "puts called, check the backtrace for the source" if s =~ /#:[a-z0-9]>*/
  end
end
```

It could also be that it's not a call to puts, but rather #inspect.

Comment: I have been trying to use this solution with no luck.

I've been trying to modify it, here is where I am at: https://gist.github.com/804506

Comment: What issues are you having? Is your version not getting invoked?

Comment: The patch seems to work as I can trigger it from the console with `puts Class.singleton_class`, but it isn't hitting on the instance that hits the log.

Comment: Yes, I tried with https://gist.github.com/805800, but this prevents my rails app from starting due to a plugin: https://github.com/therealadam/attribute_mapper/blob/master/lib/attribute_mapper.rb#L76

Answer (score 1):

You could go over all the files and search for any calls to Kernel.puts, like so:

```
find -iname "*.rb" | xargs grep -iR 'Kernel.puts'
```

However, in terms of neatness (and effectiveness), I would probably go for the solution provided by Jeff Paquette.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use, it's similar to Banang's answer but maybe even simpler. Do a grep from the directory like so:

grep -rn 'puts' .

Sure it searches everything but you can run it in whatever directory you want to limit that. That should give you the file and line number you need. You can fine tune the search criteria as you wish.